# What's an optimal method of joining tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, join

I'm wondering what's an optimal method of joining tables in this particular  case :
`Order has one Owner which has one Address`

```
addresses = []
sum = 0.0
Order.joins(owner: :adress).
where(orders: {created_at: 1.day.ago} , address: {country: 'US'} ).
each {|o| sum += o.payed;addresses << o.owner.address.to_s }
```

Is it more suitable to use `includes()` or `joins` in this particular case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your query, I think using `includes` would be appropriate. That would reduce the database query during `o.owner.address` inside the `each` loop.

Using `includes` will load the associated model objects in the memory, so that you don't have to make further db query to get each owner address.

I would suggest to use `includes`:

```
Order.includes(owner: :adress).where(orders: {created_at: 1.day.ago} , address: {country: 'US'} ).each {|o| sum += o.payed;addresses << o.owner.address.to_s }
```

When you want to apply condition on included models, you will have to add [references](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references) like this:

```
Order.includes(owner: :adress).where(orders: {created_at: 1.day.ago} , address: {country: 'US'} ).references(:owners, :adresses).each {|o| sum += o.payed;addresses << o.owner.address.to_s }
```

Comment: so to sum up - using `joins` is better for searching and `includes` is better if you use attributes of models that's are included&

Comment: Yes, if there is a possibility that you would use information of those associated objects, use includes.

Comment: You will still get three queries though, where joins() ought to give you one.

Answer (score 1):

Since the order can only have one owner, and the owner can only have one address, use joins. This allows a single query to be executed (which will be faster) without the number of rows returned being increased.

If you're sure not sure whether an order will have an owner, and an owner will have an address, then use eager_load so an outer join is used.

More info: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html